# SQL query: [Display the count of a query in a new column]

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch

I would like to display the user.name and in the second column the count of my query and I didn't know how to do that, so the expected result should look like that:

| user.name | count |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | 6 |
| user2 | 4 |
| user3 | 2 |
| user4 | 1 |

till now I am using this query:

```
select user.name 
FROM "winlogbeat-*"  
WHERE event.category = 'authentication'  
AND event.action = 'logon-failed' 
GROUP BY user.name
```

and I am getting jus the first column

| user.name |
| --- |
| user1 |
| user2 |
| user3 |
| user4 |

Could you tell me please how can I add the seconde column to my result !

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Did you research?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @HoneyBadger, In fact I need SQL just for this query as in my work don't use at all SQL, that's why I can't learn all the SQL language just for one query,

Comment: I am sorry if the question seems so easy for you  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a simple `count(*)` in your `select` statement will do the work.

Tell me if there is another problem because your problem is not clear enough